# How can I suppress/hide WMI output when using Setting an object?

Tags: powershell, wmi

How can I suppress the output from the WMI Set in my powershell function?

```
Function ChangeDefaultGateway ($NewDefaultGateway, $ComputerName)
{
    $MyIPSubnet = "192.168.16."  # This is needed to find which NIC has an assigned Default Gateway
    $NICs = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName "$ComputerName" -Filter “IPEnabled=TRUE”
    foreach($NIC in $NICs) 
    {
        if($NIC.DefaultIPGateway -match $MyIPSubnet) # fetch the NIC that has a gateway address already
        {
            write-host "Changing Gateway for $ComputerName on" $NIC.IPAddress $NIC.Description "from" $NIC.DefaultIPGateway "to" $NewDefaultGateway
            $NIC.SetGateways($NewDefaultGateway)
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the output:

```
Changing Gateway for DT-jesse on 192.168.16.108 Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection from 192.168.16.2 to 192.168.16.2


__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   :
```

Is there a way to suppress/hide the output generated by the $NIC.SetGateways($NewDefaultGateway) ?

Comment: pipe into `| Out-Null` is one of the simpler ones.

Comment: `$null = $NIC.SetGateways($NewDefaultGateway)` is another.

Comment: `[null]$NIC.SetGateways($NewDefaultGateway)`